# How to add an icon/image to routes using Aurelia?

Tags: aurelia

I wanted to add an image/icon to my navigation links that were specified in Aurelia's router configuration.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the answer on [GitHub](https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues/23). You can add a `Settings` property in router configuration which allows you to specify a path to an image. In my case I am using an SVG:

```js
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';

@inject(Router)
export class App {
  constructor(router) {
    this.router = router;
    this.router.configure(config => {
      config.title = 'Aurelia';
      config.map([
        {route: ['', 'dogs'], moduleId: './dogs', nav: true, title: 'Dogs', settings: './img/dogs-nav.svg'},
        {route: ['cats', 'cats'], moduleId: './cats', nav: true, title: 'Cats', settings: './img/cats-nav.svg'},
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li repeat.for="row of router.navigation" class="${row.isActive ? 'active' : ''}">
    <a href.bind="row.href">
      <img src="${row.settings}">
      <span>${row.title}</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: To be more precise this "settings" property is not designed especially to pass an image but for any kind of data that you need to include in a route other than the defaut ones. So I think that it would be neater to give it an object like settings:{img: 'path to image'}

Comment: @sam True. Is my example otherwise accurate?

Comment: Using `settings:{img: 'path to image'}` is more useful as it defaults to `undefined` if not set. If you're using string interpolation and leave a `settings` object empty `${row.settings}` will print as `[object Object]`